# How to set validators dynamically after control is created in angular11?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have a `function` which creates a `form`. So when form is created then after form creation i am adding validators to it like this

component.ts

```
this.proposalForm = this._utilService.createForm(this._constant.addProposalFormFileds);
if (this.proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage')) {
  this.proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').setValidators([Validators.min(0), Validators.max(80)]);
  this.proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

component.html

```
<div class="col-3">
<div class="form-group">
  <label>Fuel Part Tax Saving</label>
  <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid' : proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').errors &&
     (proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').touched || proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').dirty)}"> {{proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').errors | json}}
  <span class="help-block" *ngIf="proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').errors &&
     (proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').touched || proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').dirty)">
  <span
     *ngIf="proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').errors.min || proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').errors.max"
     class="text-danger">
  {{constants.errors.fuelPercentage}}
  </span>
  </span>
 </div>
</div>
```

but problem is that my validators are not adding to the `control` because i am printing `form` errors in template like this

```
{{proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').errors | json}}
```

but not getting any errors in it. It is showing null in template if i enter wrong value in input

What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you create a working demo on stackblitz? Did you console your proposal form after setting the validators?

Comment: Here is minimal stakblitz please see this

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ps7by8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Updated your code. Please have a look and try to put input value -1 or 81, you will get errors https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2tjkki?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the way you're updating the validator for your form control.

Try updating the validator through `controls`

```
this.proposalForm.controls['fuelAdjustmentPercentage'].setValidators([Validators.min(0), Validators.max(80)]);
```

instead of this way of updating the validators.

```
this.proposalForm.get('fuelAdjustmentPercentage').setValidators([Validators.min(0), Validators.max(80)]);
```

I am attaching the updated [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-2tjkki?file=src/app/app.component.ts) based on the demo you provided in the comments. Let me know if you're facing any issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're using reactive forms, but your form is not configured correctly. You're missing `ngForm` directive on the `<form>` element and `formControlName` on the input element.

Change your HTML template like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <div class="form-group w-75">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Budget</label>
    <input type="email" formControlName="budget" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">
      {{myForm.get('budget').errors | json}}</small>
  </div>
</form>
```